# What is the side way force on a flat membrane place perpendicular to the flow of current on one side, and stagnant water on the other

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, aerodynamics, cfd

So basically imagine a plate being placed parallel to the direction of flow of water with water flowing with a certain velocity on one side of the plate and on the other side it is almost stagnant. What would be the force on this plate? Can I use the lift equation that is used for air-foils or there is any other method?

Water flowing ... |
with Velocity .....  | Almost stagnant water 
..........................        |<--  
`     ........................       |<-- Lift Force?   
..........................      |<--  
...........................     |  
...........................     |

Comment: Tip: select the text of your diagram and use the `{}` code formatting button to force it to use fixed width font. Then you can get everything to line up.

Comment: the title contradicts the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

First off we assume you meant parallel flow because there is no flow perpendicular to a wall, there may be pressure, static and dynamic.

Depending on the current velocity, type of flow, flexibility of the plate, the case will start looking like an open channel flow.

If the plate is too flexible it could deform into convex and concave undulations giving rise to lift forces and wave creation in conjunction with the vibration of the plate into an increasingly higher amplitude, destructive flutter.

Comment: I am actually designing an anchor for a curtain that is semi-permeable. It will enclose an area under which some construction will happen. Right outside that curtain, there is a channel where the water is flowing less than 5 ft /sec. Assuming that the water inside the curtain is stagnant is basically trying to get the worst load.

Comment: you need to consider impact force, hydrostatic force, dynamic force, and even the possible negative forces on the lee side.

Comment: yep. complicated if membrane is flexible enough